# Android TextView Updates on double click only

Tags: android, textview, uitextview

I get time from a time picker dialog and convert it to a string format. I then use the setText method to set it to a TextView.The problem is that it sets the string but only after clicking the set time button not less than twice.On one try, the TextView remains empty.Any suggestions?I want it to show data on first click in the textview

```
beginTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


                    openTimePicker(true);

                    onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int min){
                            Calendar calnow = Calendar.getInstance();

                            Calendar calset = (Calendar) calnow.clone();
                            calset.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                            calset.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);

                            SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
                          time=sdf.format(calset.getTime());
                            beginTime.setText(time);




                        }
                    };




        }

    });
```

private void openTimePicker(boolean is24r) {

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

    TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, onTimeSetListener,cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),is24r);
    String begin = "TIME";
    timePicker.setTitle(begin);
    timePicker.show();



}
```

Comment: Could you provide the code that sets the text?

Comment: can you paste the code snippet that we could take a look at?

Comment: I've added the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because in `openTimePicker`, you create TimePickerDialog

```
TimePickerDialog timePicker = new TimePickerDialog(this, onTimeSetListener,cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY),cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE),is24r);
```

which require `onTimeSetListener`, but which is only created AFTER `openTimePicker` is called.

so, in the first run, it is you created a dialog with no listener, only on second run or afterwards, it is set correctly.

a quick fix: simply reverse the order like this

```
                onTimeSetListener = new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int hour, int min){
                        Calendar calnow = Calendar.getInstance();

                        Calendar calset = (Calendar) calnow.clone();
                        calset.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
                        calset.set(Calendar.MINUTE, min);

                        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");
                      time=sdf.format(calset.getTime());
                        beginTime.setText(time);




                    }
                };
                openTimePicker(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should see what listener is associated with the button you click. What you need is [setOnCLickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setOnClickListener%28android.view.View.OnClickListener%29).

Comment: Take a look at the code, I'm using a textView listener so that when pressed, It's able to pop up a time dialog.